# bluetooth headset button event

Tags: android, events, button, bluetooth, headset

**I reply my answer,I check source code "BluetoothHandsfree.java" ,it is impossible,unless recompile source code add special broadcast or add some flag to do .
I really hope google can add self defined button event on Bluetooth Api and we can  do anything on bluetooth headset button event.
Just click button ,we can use voice command and control any app in phone.Not touch screen.or speak to AI program and we can add function in own app,can press button to say something or do something.it is so easy ,but now .......:(**

I want to catch bluetooth headset button click or double click event.
we all know ,when double click the button of bluetooth headset.the phone will dialing last number .so I add filter broadcast "Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" in "onReceived()" I recevied the broadcast. so when click button ,received it ,but I found I don't know who is broadcast this message? phone or bluetooth headset.

In android 4.0.3,when camer is activiate, double click bluetooth button phone(HTC ) will take picture, but I still can not catch event? 
how can I catch it ?? or is it  impossible? Receive AT command and to do something in my app???

Trace Log :

**07-26 11:07:21.958: I/Bluetooth AT recv(1798): AT+BLDN**

**07-26 11:07:21.958: I/Bluetooth HS/HF(1798): +BLDN**

**07-26 11:07:21.958: D/Bluetooth HS/HF(1798): searchKeyString input=ActivityRecord{4124aef0 com.htc.launcher/.Launcher}, key=com.android.camera/.CameraEntry**

07-26 11:07:22.138: D/PhoneUtils(1798): checkAndCopyPhoneProviderExtras: some or all extras are missing.

07-26 11:07:22.328: W/memalloc(1444): Falling back to ashmem

07-26 11:07:22.328: D/memalloc(1444): ashmem: Allocated buffer base:0x41b15000 size:294912 fd:59

07-26 11:07:22.328: D/memalloc(2137): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52eb1000 size:294912 fd:102

07-26 11:07:22.328: I/ActivityManager(1590): Start proc net.dinglisch.android.taskerm for broadcast net.dinglisch.android.taskerm/.ReceiverStaticCallRewriter: pid=4089 uid=10140 gids={1015, 1006, 3001, 3002, 3003}

07-26 11:07:22.338: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): : Android Image

07-26 11:07:22.338: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): : RGBA_8888

07-26 11:07:22.378: I/dalvikvm(4089): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK 
07-26 11:07:22.408: D/dalvikvm(4089): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

**07-26 11:07:22.478: D/WirelessDisplayService(1590): CallReceiver: 
actionandroid.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL**

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I am struck with the same problem.

Comment: @Anenth, are You found solution?